# GoJs - update the text and default properties of node by its key in graph

Tags: javascript, gojs

I want to dynamically change the text and default properties of nodes by their key in graph. I haven't found any option in the documentation for this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are using a model.  If so, you should make sure your node template uses data bindings for the properties that you want to modify.

Please read https://gojs.net/latest/intro/usingModels.html and https://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html.  Note in particular: https://gojs.net/latest/intro/dataBinding.html#ChangingDataValues.

This uses https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#findNodeDataForKey and https://gojs.net/latest/api/symbols/Model.html#set :

```
var model = myDiagram.model;
var data = model.findNodeDataForKey(1234);
if (data) {
    model.startTransaction("modified property");
    model.set(data, "someBoundPropertyName", someNewValue);
    // ... maybe modify other properties and/or other data objects
    model.commitTransaction("modified property");
}
```

Comment: As per the given links, I didn't found any option to change the node properties run-time by its key (unique identity) for graph.